# Gibbs Sampling Code

Tags: machine-learning, montecarlo, markov-chains

Does any one here have implemented Gibbs sampling using some test. I have to implement Gibbs sampling but i have problems in it in nailing it down to implementation level.

----How and from where to choose test data?
----How to create Bayesian network based on that data? (AS far as my understanding you should have had some Bayesian network to sample from.)

If some body can guide me in this it would be great help....

Answer (score 0):

There is open-source [BUGS](http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/bugs/) software for BN inference using Gibbs Sampling. It is a really general software. I do not suggest creating a Bayes Net from the data however. You should have some data that actually corresponds to a BN. Then you can try to infer posterior probability distributions for any node in your BN given some observations.

Comment: Is this software is used to generate some sample data given already some sample data. <br>What i want is that i already have some same sample data and want to generate more sample data using gIBBS SAMPLING TECHNIQUE????

Comment: if u have a bayes net, you can sample from it as you like using gibbs.